# terraform changing the count index behaviour for remote-exec

Tags: interpolation, terraform

Trying to modify the /etc/hosts with the instance's hostname and the private IP. For an example the "/etc/hosts" file should look like the following.

```
member-1 <some private ip>
member-2 <some private ip>
```

Following code which I found from stackoverflow itself will come close to doing above but I'm having a hard time trying to understand where to increment the index by 1 (count.index + 1)  so that I can get the output mentioned above instead of member-1 to be member-0 and member-2 to be member-1.

```
variable "cluster_member_count" {
  default = "2"
}
variable "cluster_member_name_prefix" {
  default = "member-"
}
variable "aws_keypair_privatekey_filepath" {
  default = "../mykey.pem"
}


resource "aws_instance" "example" {
//
  }



resource "null_resource" "hosts_file" {
  count = "${var.cluster_member_count}"

  # Changes to any instance of the cluster requires re-provisioning
  triggers {
    cluster_instance_ids = "${join(",", aws_instance.example.*.id)}"
  }
  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    host = "${element(aws_instance.example.*.public_ip, count.index)}"
    user = "ec2-user"
    private_key = "${file(var.aws_keypair_privatekey_filepath)}"
  }
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      # Adds all cluster members' IP addresses to /etc/hosts (on each member)
      "echo '${join("\n", formatlist("%v", aws_instance.example.*.private_ip))}' | awk 'BEGIN{ print \"\\n\\n# Cluster members:\" }; { print $0 \ ${var.cluster_member_name_prefix}\ NR-1 }' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null",
    ]
  }
}
```

Please can a newbie get some help?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to read this to get a summary of what arrays are, but there are probably better resources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#One-dimensional_arrays. After that, you have chosen a really awkward and difficult route to populate a hosts file on a server. I would really recommend something like this example instead: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/index.html. It would be much easier and safer.

Comment: Thanks but most of the examples are surrounding single resource hence the struggle to understand how to apply principles when multiple resources need creating.

Answer (score 0):

When I have done similar things before with count, I am pretty sure I've done something like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "my_resource" {
  count = "${var.cluster_count}"

  name = "cluster-node-${count.index+1}"
}
```

So in your example, you're going to want to add the ${count.index+1} after you mention ${var.cluster_member_name_prefix} I believe.

However as @matt-schuchard mentions, maybe templating is a better way to go as your current implementation in my opinion isn't very readable.

You should be able to pass variables into the template (like the number of members you need for example), and then use that variable with a loop to generate the the correct file configuration you need.

Templates are very handy for that sort of thing.

Additionally, if you are going to be running a lot of commands on the servers (for installations and such), potentially a tool like Ansible would be a good fit instead of remote_exec command in terraform.

Some links that may help:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/index.html 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#string-templates